# Accessing an instance of a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

As an exercise to learn more about about how jQuery plugins work, I'd like to stop auto scrolling in a jQuery carousel plugin from the javascript console (using Firebug with Firefox).

In a demo of the plugin [here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html), it's trivially easy to stop the autoscrolling. I just use the following code in the console.

```
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel('stopAuto')
```

However, on [this site](http://live.feathercap.net/xlearn/) which uses an older version of the above plugin (and an older version of jQuery) the equivalent code:

```
$('#showcaseHolder').jcarousel('stopAuto')
```

Does not work.

One difference I noticed is that in the first (working) case the call to jcarosel returns 'undefined' and in the second (not working) case it returns the element itself.

What's the difference between these two cases? How can I call 'stopAuto' on that second site? Why does it return the element in the second case?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: The difference in these cases is the versions... Newer versions are different from older versions. Read the docs, it's all there.

Comment: @Andrew the documentation for the older version of the plugin or of jquerry? I can't documentation for the older version of the plugin, do you have a link?

Comment: You can find the documentation in the sourcecode. Just right click the page and click sourcecode. Sift through the text until you come across this one: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/xlearn/js/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>` If you use firefox there should be a direct link on it, so it's just a simple click and there you go. The developer have some documentation in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are doing this for learning how plugins work.. if you were to call `$('#mycaousel').jcarousel('stopAuto')` in the new version, it returns undefined because it is not intended to be chained. In the old version, it returns the element itself because the plugin developer intended on this being chainable, meaning that you could maybe do something like, `$('#mycaousel').jcarousel('stopAuto').jcarousel('startAuto')`

in the oldskool version:

jCarousel function accepts an 'options' object, which allows you to specify optional params in an object like: `{scroll: 1}`

Without reading any documentation on this older version and from looking at the code, I would assume that you could supply '0' to an 'auto' optional param and this would turn off autoscroll. Right now you have auto set to 15, meaning it should autoscroll after 1.5 seconds

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#showcaseHolder').jcarousel({
        scroll:1,
        itemLoadCallback: function (carousel, state) {
            JQUERY_CARA_LEFT = carousel;            
        },
        auto: 0, /* was auto: 15 */
        wrap:'both' 
    });
    jQuery('#showcaseHolderRight').jcarousel({
        scroll:1,
        itemLoadCallback: function (carousel, state) {
            JQUERY_CARA_RIGHT = carousel;           
        },
        auto: 0, /* was auto: 15 */
        wrap:'both' 
    }); 
});
```

Note: you can also remove `auto: 0` because if you do not supply the optional 'auto' param it defaults to '0'

**UPDATE (based off of comments):**

I could just tell you the answer but I want to explain how I got to this:

In the jcarousel.js source, this is the key part:

```
// Create shortcut for internal use
var $jc = $.jcarousel;
 ...

$jc.fn.extend({
 ...
startAuto: function(s) { ... },  /* s = number of seconds to autoscroll by */
stopAuto: function() { ... }
 ...
```

This means that 'startAuto(s)' and 'stopAuto()' are parameters of the jcarousel object.

Since in your code, when you instantiate your jcarousel objects you place one in var JQUERY_CARA_LEFT and another in JQUERY_CARA_RIGHT, this is the format you would need to use:

To start at any time:

```
JQUERY_CARA_LEFT.jcarousel.startAuto(15);
// or
JQUERY_CARA_RIGHT.jcarousel.startAuto(15);
```

And to stop at any time:

```
JQUERY_CARA_LEFT.jcarousel.stopAuto();
// or
JQUERY_CARA_RIGHT.jcarousel.stopAuto();
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about chaining, that was very helpful! Is there any way to change the auto option after the instance was loaded? I'd like to be able to stop auto scrolling after it's started and then eventually restart it (though if I could figure out how to stop it, I'd probably be able to restart it.) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: NM thanks to your answer I figured it out. I just called JQUERY_CARA_LEFT.stopAuto(). If you have a chance though, I'd still like to know why I wasn't able to call the function by using a jquerry selector? Thanks again!!!

Comment: The reason you can't call the function through a jquery selector is because you instantiate a new jcarousel. In the documentation it reads `$.extend.fn.jcarousel  ...` so every time you do `$("#").jacarousel()` you're no long referring to the one in the document, you're referring to the one you just created. The only way you can reference it is through an already defined variable, or global variable. Like you did just now.

Comment: @ShadowScripter, Thanks!! So if it weren't for this line 'JQUERY_CARA_LEFT = carousel;' in the callback function you wouldn't be able to access the instance of the jcarousel to change the auto scrolling once it loaded?

Comment: That's right. You have to have to have an actual reference of the current object in the document. The callback function returns the existing carousel object and is therefore accessible.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Just need one more tid bit of information before I've fully wrapped my head around this though :). In the newer version of the jcarousel, you can access the object without using the callback to store an instance (see the selector and call in my question above). Is the because of a changes in jQuerry from 1.3 to 1.4, or changes to the plugin?

Comment: @evan good catch I didn't pay attention to your 'itemLoadCallback' and correct me if i'm wrong but i think that 'itemLoadCallback' is optional in the old jcarousel script? Say you took it out, then I think you would then be able to access the jcarousel object on an element like:  $('#elementID').jcarousel.stopAuto();  which would still be different from how you would do this in the new jcarousel script.

Comment: @BubmleB2na yeah, I think you're right! Thanks again for all of your help!